# Get User Rights Assignment values in Local Computer Setting using VBScript and WMI

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, wmi, vbscript

I'd like to get all the values of User Rights Assignment in Local Computer Setting using VBScript and WMI. Is there a way I can do this with VBScript and WMI?

Thanks.

Comment: It's buried somewhere within the root\rsop\computer WMI namespace, I just know it, but I've been working on this for a couple hours and I have yet to arrive at a silver bullet solution. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I did in C# .NET based on [Jay Adams link](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/computermanagement/policy/#EnumPolUserPrivs.htm) and the [RSOP_UserPrivilegeRight class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375080(v=vs.85).aspx), I guess this is easily portable to VBS:

```
using System.Management;    

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\localhost\root\rsop\computer");
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM RSOP_UserPrivilegeRight");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

scope.Connect();

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("=> User right: {0}, precedence: {1}", m["UserRight"], m["precedence"]);

    Action<string> action = new Action<string>(Console.WriteLine);
    Array.ForEach((string[])m["AccountList"], action);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for: http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/computermanagement/policy/#EnumPolUserPrivs.htm

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I think so when the link takes you to information that directly solves the user's question. The code needed no modification and I felt it redundant to copy/paste when we could all take advantage of a "hyperlink".

Comment: You may consider following my comment's link. It will provide you some of the StackExchange community's discussion on this topic.